# Which birds are capable of flying both forward and backwards?

Tags: zoology, ornithology

Very random question - but it's often said that the hummingbird is the only bird that can fly backwards (for example, https://www.worldatlas.com/articles/which-is-the-only-bird-that-can-fly-backward.html).

Is this true? Aren't there any other birds that can fly both forward and backwards? Is it some kind of bird category of its own?

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! We encourage you to do some research on your own and then, informed by what you have learned, ask any questions you might still have (ideally with references to reliable sources). For this question you should also carefully define what you mean by flying backwards (many birds flying into the wind can move backwards)! ——— Please also take the time to take the [tour] and then go through the help pages starting with [Ask] questions effectively on this site. Thanks! 